# Gradle check environment variable before running unit tests

Tags: android, testing, build, gradle

I want to check whether an environment variable is set ONLY before running my unit tests in a Gradle build.

I've tried to use following type of code:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    task ->
    task.doFirst {
        if (isEnvironmentVariableSet)
            throw new RuntimeException("Environment variable XXX is not set")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this code always checks whether the environment variable is set, even when you are just doing `./gradlew build`.

Presumably it's because this diagram shows that http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/img/javaPluginTasks.png
'test' tasks are always run, even when building.

However, if that is the case, why don't my unit tests get run when I do the `./gradlew build` command?  Perhaps they are run, but if they are, their failure/success is not reported.  Can someone explain, and suggest the best way of doing the check I am looking for?

PS I am running an Android build.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "just doing build"? `build` is doing a full build, which includes running tests.

Comment: I looked back at my projects, and yes, `./gradlew build` always does `test`.  However, if you do `./gradlew zipalignProdBuild` it does not do test.  Nor does Android Studio run tests when you Build...Make Project; nor when you run an Android Studio project, which apparently invokes `./gradlew assembleDebug`, or `./gradlew assembleRelease`, etc.  Seems to be an inconsistent use of nomenclature, hmmm (probably on the Android side)?  Anyway, I'm left with the much more minor question, is there a neater way to do the environment variable check?  Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are looking for a different way to do the env variable check. If you don't want to run tests, don't run `build`, but a more suitable task.

Comment: It just feels a bit clunky.  I'd rather do a single check at the start of the test 'phase' rather than at the start of each individual unit test, which is what I thought it was doing now (?).  And even if not I thought there might be a simpler syntax like `Tests.each { $it.doFirst ... }.`

Comment: The code is checking once per `Test` task (not once per test), which seems appropriate. (By default, there will only be one `Test` task.) Other than replacing `task -> task.` with `it.`, there is no simpler syntax.

Comment: You can also exclude task with `-X` switch. See here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html